# How do I filter or re/assemble and collect data-items where each of an item's many color values meets a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, reduce

I have this sample data and I wanted to filter it where the colors are less than 20 or equal to 20:

```
const data = [
  { name: "Item1", colors: { green: 8 } },
  { name: "Item2", colors: { green: 7, black: 6 } },
  { name: "Item3", colors: { green: 20, yellow: 31, pink: 36 } },
  { name: "Item4", colors: { black: 39, red: 21 } },
];
```

I recreated this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-margulis-yy1moz?file=/src/App.js

I tried this:

```js
const data = [{colors: { green: 8 },name: "Item1"},{colors: { Black: 6, Green: 7 },name: "Item2"},{colors: { Green: 20, Yellow: 31, Pink: 36 },name: "Item2"},{colors: { Black: 39, Red: 21 },name: "Item4"}];

const newData = data.filter((item) => {
  return Object.entries(item.colors).filter((c) => c[1] < 20);
});

console.log(newData);
```

It does not correctly filter. I can still see all of the items even if they are more than 20

The expected output would be to show the filtered data:

```
Item1, green: 8
Item2, Black: 6, Green: 7,
Item3, Green: 20
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `filter` is doing - it returns an array, which is always "truthy" therefore your outer filter does nothing, since all items will pass the filter regardless - the error is because your first element has no property called `color`

Comment: @Bravo I edited it but I can still see the items even if the number of the colors are more than 20

Comment: _"where the colors are less than 20 or equal to 20"_ - each of them individually, or in summation?

Comment: To something like `Item1, green: 8
Item2, Black: 6, Green: 7,
Item3, Green: 20`

Comment: @CBroe yes, that's right

Comment: What is the expected result? A string? `Item1, green: 8 Item2, Black: 6, Green: 7, Item3, Green: 20` doesn't neither look like an array nor like an object.

Comment: `Item1, green: 8 Item2, Black: 6, Green: 7, Item3, Green: 20` --> do you need it like a `"string"` - like this: `"Item1, green: 8 Item2, Black: 6, Green: 7, Item3, Green: 20"`?

Comment: @jsN00b sorry, what I meant was to filter the data whose colors are less than 20 and eliminate those that are not

Comment: There are several ways in which the output after the filter can be. I guess if that's all you need, there are at least couple of answers (I think the ones by R4ncid and Hassan) below that does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter on color value using `array#filter` and create a new `colors` object and push it in result using `array#reduce`.

```js
const data = [ { colors: { green: 8 }, name: "Item1" }, { colors: { Black: 6, Green: 7 }, name: "Item2" }, { colors: { Green: 20, Yellow: 31, Pink: 36 }, name: "Item2" }, { colors: { Black: 39, Red: 21 }, name: "Item4" } ],
      result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const colors = Object.entries(o.colors).filter(([,val]) => val <= 20);
        if(colors.length) {
          r.push({ colors: Object.fromEntries(colors), name: o.name });
        }
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think think filter wont do the job here because is an object instead of an array we can do a combination of reduce and more methods to achieve this, i also spotted typos in your data so i fixed as well

```js
const data = [
  {
    colors: { green: 8 },
    name: 'Item1',
  },
  {
    colors: { black: 6, green: 7 },
    name: 'Item2',
  },
  {
    colors: { green: 20, yellow: 31, pink: 36 },
    name: 'Item3',
  },
  {
    colors: { black: 39, red: 21 },
    name: 'Item4',
  },
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, v) => {
  const colors = Object.keys(v.colors).filter(c => v.colors[c] <= 20);
  if (!acc[v.name] && colors.length) {
    const values = {};
    colors.forEach(c => {
      values[c] = v.colors[c];
    });
    acc[v.name] = values;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach was to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the given data structure **twice**.

The 1st reduce cycle mimics filter functionality. Filtering directly does not work since items might only partially meet the criteria of featuring color values which are lower than or equal to `20`.

Thus one needs to (re)create/assemble such an item with just the matching key-value pairs which is taken care of by the 2nd reduce tasks where the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of a color item are getting processed, and the new color item programmatically gets aggregated via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Back again within the 1st reduce cycle the final decision whether to collect (not quite filter) an item is made upon the just created color object. In case this object features at least one key it is a valid object; thus a final item can be created from the original item's data and the new color object.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Item1", colors: { green: 8 } },
  { name: "Item2", colors: { green: 7, black: 6 } },
  { name: "Item3", colors: { green: 20, yellow: 31, pink: 36 } },
  { name: "Item4", colors: { black: 39, red: 21 } },
];
console.log(
  data
    .reduce((result, { name, colors, ...rest }) => {

      // (try to) create a new color item
      // with all the key-value pairs where
      // `value` meets the OP's criteria.
      const newColorItem = Object
        .entries(colors)
        .reduce((item, [key, value]) => {

          if (value <= 20) {
            Object.assign(item, { [key]: value });
          }
          return item;

        }, {});

      // for every created and valid new color item
      // push a newly created item into the `result`
      // array where this item's data structure equals
      // the structure of the currently processed
      // original item.
      if (Object.keys(newColorItem).length >= 1) {
        result
          .push({
            name,
            colors: newColorItem,
            ...rest,
          });
      }
      return result;

    }, [])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const data = [{
    colors: {
      green: 8
    },
    name: "Item1"
  },
  {
    colors: {
      Black: 6,
      Green: 7
    },
    name: "Item2"
  },
  {
    colors: {
      Green: 20,
      Yellow: 31,
      Pink: 36
    },
    name: "Item2"
  },
  {
    colors: {
      Black: 39,
      Red: 21
    },
    name: "Item4"
  }
];

const filtered = data.map(d => ({ ...d,
      colors: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d.colors).filter(([_, v]) => v <= 20))
    })).filter(d => Object.keys(d.colors).length > 0)

    console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

as `filter` returns the array (an empty array is a truthy value) so your inner filter is always true hence it is giving all the data.

```js
const data = [
  {
    color: { green: 8 },
    name: "Item1"
  },
  {
    color: { Black: 6, Green: 7 },
    name: "Item2"
  },
  {
    color: { Green: 20, Yellow: 31, Pink: 36 },
    name: "Item3"
  },
  {
    color: { Black: 39, Red: 21 },
    name: "Item4"
  }
];

const newData = data.flatMap(item => {
  const filteredColors = Object.entries(item.color).filter(c => c[1] <= 20);
  return filteredColors.length ? { name: item.name, colors: filteredColors } : [];
});

console.log(newData);
```